# Is there a Windows Phone 7 equivalent to Android noHistory activity attribute?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, lifecycle

NOTICE: There has been some confusion, so let me clarify that I'm asking how to achieve something in Windows Phone 7, by comparing it to similar functionality in Android.

Question:

Learning about navigation between pages in Windows Phone 7, I implemented two-way navigation between two pages, A and B, so you can navigate from page A to B and B to A.

For illustrative purposes, let's say I navigate like this: A->B->A->B

When backing out of the application I'll be forced through each of the pages again, where ideally I only want to go through A once, and/or B once and then exit the application.

In Android you can achieve that by setting the noHistory attribute to "true" on the activity, but what about WP7?

UPDATE: Using RemoveBackEntry as suggested by keyboardP I achieved what I was looking for. For anyone else interested, this is the code I used:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FirstPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 7.0, there's no method that removes any pages from the navigation stack. However, there's a recipe you can download that will help deal with `circular navigation`. You can download it the [Non-Linear Navigation Service from here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7) and it's based on [this article](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx).

I don't know if that recipe is compatible with 7.1 (Mango), but there is a new method introduced in Mango within the NavigationService called [RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). You could perform some calculations to figure out how many times to remove the last entry so that the user ends up on the first page when they click the `back button`.